# Is there any fast way to convert all of the values in dataframe - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

There is a data frame like below:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 84 | 15 |
| 51 | 42 |
| 2 | 10 |

Each value shows the position of a string in a list. For example, list A=[Cat, Dog, Cow, ...]
Therefore, the first value in column A should be Dog.
How can I replace this values in this data frame fast.
This data frame has more than 1 million rows.
I wrote the code below, but it seems that it takes ages to run!!

```
for i in range (0, len(df)):
   a = df.iloc[i,0]
   df.iloc[i,0] = A[a]
   b = df.iloc[i,1]
   df.iloc[i,1] = B[b]
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply), [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't believe your code is particularly bad from an efficiency point of view. It's likely to take a while given that you have such a large dataframe.

I would suggest though that the below code is more elegant when applying a function to a column in a dataframe:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].map(lambda x: A[x])
df['B'] = df['B'].map(lambda x: B[x])
```

Comment: another option is to replace `map` by `apply` . I don't know which is more efficient, so it might be interesting to try both approaches

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy which is much faster than Pandas.
Try the following:

```
valsA=['Cat', 'Dog', 'Cow'] * 100
valsA=np.array(valsA)
valsB=['Dog', 'Cat', 'Cow'] * 100
valsB=np.array(valsB)

df['A']=valsA.take(df['A'])
df['B']=valsB.take(df['B'])

>>> print(df)

     A    B
0  Dog  Dog
1  Cat  Dog
2  Cat  Dog
3  Cow  Cat
```

Comment: Nice, creative solution. First time seeing such usecase of numpy +1

Answer (score 0):

You can Use apply.

Generally when using apply output is of type pd.Series, but when `result_type='expand'`, the result of apply is unwrapped over columns and returns a pd.DataFrame

Below example is an illustration

```py
>>> A = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Cow']
>>> B = ['Catb', 'Dogb', 'Cowb']
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])
>>> df.apply(lambda x: [A[x['A']], B[x['B']]], axis=1, result_type='expand')
     0    1
0  Dog  Cowb
1  Dog  Cowb
2  Dog  Cowb
```

Also one more method using map but without using lambda [List comprehension vs map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map)

```py
>>> df['A'] = df['A'].map(A.__getitem__)
>>> df['B'] = df['B'].map(B.__getitem__)
```